# jQuery composition event is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ime

I do not want users to enter numbers or special character within a name input field and I have achieved this with the following code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".txtOnly").keypress(function(e) {
       var key = e.keyCode;
       if(key < 97 || key > 122) {
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   });
});
```

But I want to avoid numbers and special characters from microsoft IME Japanese Keyboard as well though the `keypress` does not work so I am using a jQuery composition event which is working but it always returns `undefined`, so I am unable to get the key code or the value this way.

**My Code:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".txtOnly").on('compositionupdate', function(e) {
       var keyCode = e.keyCode;
       alert(keyCode); //Undefined 
       console.log(e.data); //Undefined 
   });
});
```

How I can get the keycode using a composition event or what other solution can I use for the Microsoft IME Japanese Keyboard?

Comment: Try console.log(e) and see whats the result.

Comment: @Grumpy I already tried this and it is displaying undefined for data, keycode, code, which and for many other attributes